# Can I pass a value of an option to the same file in php with Ajax?

Tags: php, html

I am making a room reservation system in PHP. I'm new to Ajax and PHP. I want to send the value of a selected option to the PHP section of my file which is at the top so that I can run a query with it. I tried using Ajax but it seems like it's not working.

```
if(isset($_POST['value'])){
    $room_id = $_POST['value'];
    echo "<script>alert('$room_id')</script>";
}
```

This is the part of my PHP code.

```
<select required class="form-select form-select-lg" name="room" id="room">
    <option selected disabled value="">Select a room</option>
    <?php
        foreach($options as $option){
    ?>
    <option value=<?php echo $option['room_id'];?> ><?php echo $option['room_name']?></option>
    <?php
        }
    ?>
</select>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#room').on('change', function(){
        var value = this.value;
        $.ajax({
            url: '',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {
                'value': value
            },

            success: function(data){
                // alert(data);
            }
        });
    })
</script>
```

The alert(data) part of the code works just fine. It pops up an alert with the value of the selected option but the alert in the php section of my code does not output anything. Is there anything that I'm doing wrong?

Comment: PHP works on the server side and it can't update a page that was already loaded. But you can take some values with AJAX request and update the page with the help of Javascript.

Comment: _"but the alert in the php section of my code does not output anything"_ - you made a _background_ request, so whatever response you send, will not automatically get the same treatment, as if you loaded a normal document in the foreground. Just because you responded with a `script` element, does not mean anything will automatically _interpret_ this as HTML. You should not be responding with any HTML or script code here to begin with - but with JSON. What to do/display on the client side then, would be determined by your client-side script, based on what that data structure contains.

Comment: Instead of `echo "<script>alert('$room_id')</script>";` use `echo $room_id;` and in js use `success: function(data){ alert(data);  }`